# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error-0x8007000d

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I encountered this error when I tried to host my asp .net core project on local iis.

I have installed the asp .net hosting bundle, checked the permissions to my web.config file but still of no use.
[image: Error page]

My web.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\SampleApp1.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: e4b7dcc7-c9c3-48c5-9a12-0a9ee0c9ac2c-->
```

My asp .net version is 3.1.201.
Also, usually at the error page you should see the physical path as well but in my case that's empty though I set the physical path to my web files.

Comment: I think the server bundle installation failed. You can use Jexus Manager to generate a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html to see more details. Rerun the bundle installer to see if that can fix the issue.

Comment: As far as I know, there are many reasons for this error. According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x8007000d), This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed XML element. Delete the space in front of the XML Declaration (the first line) and try again, your error page likely tells you precisely what line your error is line.

Comment: The problem is that the config Error usually tells us what's wrong but in my case it's blank

Comment: Are there any error messages in the Event Viewer? Or you can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to get detailed error information. under normal circumstances, the cause of this error may also be URL rewriting module is missing, you can try to install URL rewriting module via web platform installer.